# Convert 1 digit to HH:mm:ss in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

How in php I can convert 1 digit, e.g:

```
0
1
2
...
17
18
19
```

To a full time representation like:

```
00:00:00
01:00:00
02:00:00
...
17:00:00
18:00:00
19:00:00
```

I tried working with `strtotime()` and `date()` but didn't really get the hang out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/sprintf) with zero padding to two digits:

```
foreach (range(0, 23) as $i) {
   echo sprintf('%02d:00:00' . PHP_EOL, $i);
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/d5DQa).

Comment: This. There is no reason to use date/time functions unless you are working with a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `mktime()` function, like this:

```
echo date('H:i:s', mktime(15, 0, 0));
```

returns:

```
15:00:00
```

Sample Output: https://3v4l.org/vuenr